# SQL Server copy muptiple rows of same table changing only date of a datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to copy all rows of a table, changing only the date part of the `Datetime`. The query I've been testing in sqlfiddle, returns record count of 0, and obviously the `@newDate + SameTime` isn't part of the query, but I put it there so you know what I want to do.

```
CREATE TABLE Games
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    [GameTypeId] int, 
    [DateCreated] datetime, 
    [DateTime] datetime, 
    [Location] int
);

INSERT INTO Games ([GameTypeId], [DateCreated], [DateTime], [Location])
VALUES ('1', GETDATE(), '8/21/2021 8:00:00', '1'),
       ('2', GETDATE(), '8/21/2021 9:00:00', '1'),
       ('2', GETDATE(), '8/21/2021 10:00:00', '1');
```

The query I'm testing to copy the rows but is not working:

```
 INSERT INTO Games (GameTypeId, DateCreated, DateTime, Location) 
     SELECT 
         GameTypeId, GETDATE(), @newDate + SameTime, Location 
     FROM
         Games 
     WHERE
         CONVERT(date, DateTime) = '8/21/2021'
```

The results from the initial insert:

```
Id   GameTypeID   DateCreated   DateTime             Location
--------------------------------------------------------------
1       1         8/15/2021     8/21/2021 8:00:00        1
2       1         8/15/2021     8/21/2021 9:00:00        1
3       1         8/15/2021     8/21/2021 10:00:00       1
```

And after the copy rows query, the results I want (but can't get). I want to copy everything to a new row, except the date only needs to change. The time stays the same:

```
4       1         8/20/2021     8/28/2021 8:00:00        1
5       1         8/20/2021     8/28/2021 9:00:00        1
6       1         8/20/2021     8/28/2021 10:00:00       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use date arithmetic:

```
INSERT INTO Games (GameTypeId, DateCreated, DateTime, Location) 
     SELECT GameTypeId, DATEADD(day, 5, DateCreated),
            DATEADD(day, 7, DateTime), location
     FROM Games 
     WHERE CONVERT(date, DateTime) = '2021-08-21'
```

Comment: Although the new date is 7 days in the future, it may not always be, so a date will be selected on client site, such as 8/28/2021. And I should have left DateCreated off of it, because it just gets the current date of the row creation and doesn't need to be a specific date

Comment: In other words, it needs to be like @newDate, where the new date is selected, but the time is not updated.

Comment: @mlg74 . . . You can put whatever expression is appropriate.  Based on your question, this seems like the most appropriate answer.

Comment: how do you program the sql so that if the user chooses a date 8 days in the future, it is dateadd(day, 8 ..), or if user chooses a date 15 days in the future. Then the expression would be dateadd(day 15 ...) and so forth.

Comment: @mlg74 . . . You would use a parameter:  `dateadd(day, @days, . . .)`.